# Where does the "let" comes from in this applicative reduction in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

[image]

In the second equality I have trouble understanding why there is a 'let' ?
didn't the let((ident) (expression) (expr0)) would reduce to expr0?
In our case it would reduce to f(f(10)) so why does it reappear in the second line?

We just started learning about functional programming in my college classes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be taking the identity that

```
(let ((x e)) body)
```

is the same as

```
((lambda (x) body) e)
```

but running it in the opposite direction, by turning a lambda application into a `let` expression. I don't find this derivation very helpful, but it's not wrong.